# Is it possible to set individual shipping prices in Woocommerce?

Tags: e-commerce, plugins, magento

I currently have a store running on Bigcommerce, but unfortunately it doesn't offer the functionality that I require. I am debating whether to use a magento/wordpress install or wordpress/woocommerce.

Does anybody out there know if it is possible with woocommerce (or additional plugins) to perform the following:

Set an individual item with a fixed shipping price to different regions/countries.

Offer a free shipping option on orders of a particular item over a given amount.

I believe this would possible with magento, but it appears to be a quite heavy weight option for a wordpress blog/ e-commerce store.

Thanks in advance for any assistance with the above.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just to help you out ... Wordpress and Magento are comparable as they are both PHP content management systems. However Magento doesn't compare to WooCommerce in the way you mention it above.

For example: you may not need WordPress if you installed Magento.  But you have to install WordPress to use WooCommerce.

What you are looking for is Table Rate Shipping this is part of the Magento functions, but you'd need to buy the [Table Rate premium extension](http://www.woothemes.com/extension/table-rate-shipping-2/) from WooCommerce to achieve this.

Comment: Hi @Damien, cheers for response. Yep I appreciate magento and wordpress are standalone PHP content management systems. I have experience with wordpress and was considering using the two together. Table Rate Shipping appears to be exactly the thing I'm after though. Its a shame there is no way of giving the plugin a trial run first though! Thanks for advice and the push in the right direction.

Comment: FYI -- you'd even have to buy Table Rate Shipping if you did install Magento. But glad to have helped -- unfortunately there is no 'trial' option, just like all those other App Stores :)

Comment: thanks again. Yep it looks like you need to purchase both! Just need to decide now which one to go with.

Comment: Hi -- that's easy WooCommerce. Setting up Magento as a whole new CMS is very time consuming and not for the faint-hearted. Contact me via Twitter or website if you get stuck with Woocommerce

Answer (score -1):

I have a customer that was using BigCommerce. They moved to Magento and regretted it since Magento is massive overkill in terms of bloat and resource usage unless you really need all those bells and whistles. So they subsequently moved to WooCommerce where they can add features as necessary, and use a hosting platform that is far less expensive.

Comment: Didn't really answer the question here. Are the things the OP asked possible with Woocommerce?